# Calculate surface area of ggplot stat_summary2d and stat_bin2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I've got a map in .shp format and I plot it with `ggplot2`, obtaining the following

[image]

then I plot some points on top with

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), data=map,
               colour = "grey40", fill = "seagreen") +
  coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(55, 0, 0)) +
  stat_summary2d(mapping=aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, z=value),
                 data=data, bin=200, fun = sum)
```

from `?stat_bin2d`

```
bins     numeric vector giving number of bins in both vertical 
         and horizontal directions. Set to 30 by default.
```

Basically I would like to know the surface area of the bins so I thought let's divide the plot area by 200 (my `bins` value) in both direction. **Q**: what does `ggplot` divide by 200? I can have the maximum area occupied by the map with `range(lat); range(lon), however the other layer in principal can span farther the map borders. So, have I to plot first all the layer and then "look" which scale ggplot chose or have I to set a fixed "zoom" to the map to make sure I know exactly what is divided by the number of bins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the option `binwidth`

`binwidth = c(1/43, 1/69)`

the above set the bins at 1 squared mile considering the average England latitude...